# compare array to a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, indexof

I'm trying to see if a value exists in an array. The index of function works when I manually put in a string. However when I use the value's of a foreach loop it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? (see picture for more info)

```
                $groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter { GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and GroupScope -eq "Global"  } -Properties isCriticalSystemObject | Where-Object { !($_.IsCriticalSystemObject) -and !($_.Name -eq "DnsUpdateProxy") }
                
            $currentFlexAssets = (Get-ITGlueFlexibleAssets -filter_flexible_asset_type_id $api__flex_asset_id -filter_organization_id $api__org_id )                
            
            
            # Delete groups from IT Glue that no longer exist in AD
            $api__flex_asset_id = ''
            Foreach ($asset in $currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.name) {
                        
                $asset
                
                $fa_index = [array]::indexof($groups.Name ,'$asset')
            
                $fa_index
                                    
                #if($fa_index -eq '-1') {
                #   Write-Host "Destroy = " $asset 
                #}
            }
```

[powershell console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI8TP.png)

Comment: `[array]::indexof($groups.Name, $asset)`

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias already commented, you should not use single quotes around the `$asset` variable. By using single quotes, the IndexOf is comparing against the literal value '$asset', not what this variable contains.

The `IndexOf()` method either gives you an **int** value of `-1` if not found, or the actual array index of the string you're looking for.
However, be aware that IndexOf is Case-Sensitive and because of that may not find what you want.

To make it compare case-insensitive, you can do this:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security' -and GroupScope -eq 'Global'" -Properties isCriticalSystemObject | 
          Where-Object { !($_.IsCriticalSystemObject) -and !($_.Name -eq "DnsUpdateProxy") }

$currentFlexAssets = (Get-ITGlueFlexibleAssets -filter_flexible_asset_type_id $api__flex_asset_id -filter_organization_id $api__org_id )

# make all items in the array lowercase for the IndexOf() method
$groupsNames = $groups.Name | ForEach-Object { $_.ToLower() }
```

Then, inside your `foreach ($asset in $currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.name)` loop do:

```
$fa_index = [array]::IndexOf($groupsNames, $asset.ToLower())
if($fa_index -lt 0) {   # IndexOf() returns an int, so son't quote here
     Write-Host "Destroy = $asset"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the quotes where still there due to testing.

When I run the script setting all values to lower still $fa_index only returns -1 resulting in destroying all the assets.

The value $asset comes from $currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.name and seems therefore not to be a string value which I can compare with IndexOf is that correct?

Comment: @SebastiaanCastenmiller Then I suggest to add a Write-Host to see what you get with `$currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.name`. I cannot test that myself.

Comment: this is what powershell returns on write-host $currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.name

---------------------------------

GG_Sales
 GG_Marketing
 GG_Buitendienst
 GG_Inkoop
 Folder Redirection Users
 test

-----------------------------

Comment: @SebastiaanCastenmiller Is that one string or an array? Are the lines with dashes part of the name attribute value?

Comment: there all on a separate line

Comment: @SebastiaanCastenmiller So it seems to be an array allright, but are those lines with dashes also part of it? Can you tell me what `Write-Host ($currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.name).GetType().FullName` shows?